# I am not getting click event for one button of webpage in WKWebview , and how can I add the click event to wkwebview with using java script

Tags: ios, swift

I have posted the delegate method I used if there is no event for button action how can I add that event with javascript .how can I use the functionalists in my view controller.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print(#function)
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
        if url.absoluteString.contains("ios-development-course") {
            // this means login successful
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
        else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have posted the delegate method I used if there is no event for button action how can I add that event  with javascript  .how can I use the functionalists in my view controller.

Comment: a button click is usually a "linkActivated" type navigation

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thanks for the replay   I am opening adobe page in my webview there I have to click signin button but when I click that button I am not getting any response to my delegate method in web there are using javascript to handle that button action how can I use javascript to handle the button.

Comment: anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button which is basically a link in web view, the navigation happens in web view.

There is a delegate method you can use to allow or cancel that navigation.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

  var shouldLoad = true
  if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated.  
      //user clicked button on web view   
      decisionHandler(shouldLoad ? .allow : .cancel)
  }
}
```